# generate a json within bitbucket pipeline

Tags: json, bitbucket, bitbucket-pipelines, dbt

Running this `dbt docs generate`command generates a **catalog.json** file in the target folder. The process works well locally.

```
    feature/dbt-docs:
      - step:
          name: 'setup dbt and generate docs'
          image: fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0
          script:
            - cd dbt_folder
            - dbt docs generate 
            - cp target/catalog.json ../catalog.json
```

After generating the catalog.json file, I want to upload it to s3 in the next step. I copy it from the target folder to the root folder and then I upload it somewhat like this:

```
      - step:
          name: 'Upload to S3'
          image: python:3.7.2
          script:
            - aws s3 cp catalog.json s3://testunzipping/
```

However, I get an error that:

```
+ aws s3 cp catalog.json s3://testunzipping/
The user-provided path catalog.json does not exist.
```

Although the copy command works well locally, it seems to not generate the file properly within the bitbucket pipeline. Is there any other way that I can save the content of `catalog.json` in some variable in the first step and then later upload it to S3?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In bitbucket pipelines, each step has its own build environment. To be able to share things between steps, you should use `artifacts`.

You may want to try the steps below.

```
feature/dbt-docs:
      - step:
          name: 'setup dbt and generate docs'
          image: fishtownanalytics/dbt:1.0.0
          script:
            - cd dbt_folder
            - dbt docs generate 
            - cp target/catalog.json ../catalog.json
          artifacts:
            - catalog.json
      - step:
          name: 'Upload to S3'
          image: python:3.7.2
          script:
            - aws s3 cp catalog.json s3://testunzipping/
```

Reference : https://support.atlassian.com/bitbucket-cloud/docs/use-artifacts-in-steps/